# Parsing XML into CSV using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, csv, nokogiri

I am trying to figure out how to get Make and Model out of XML returned from a URL and put them into a CSV.  Here is the XML returned from the URL:

```
<VINResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://basicvalues.pentondata.com/">
  <Vehicles>
    <Vehicle>
      <ID>131497</ID>
      <Product>TRUCK</Product>
      <Year>1993</Year>
      <Make>Freightliner</Make>
      <Model>FLD12064T</Model>
      <Description>120'' BBC Alum Air Cond Long Conv. (SBA) Tractor w/48'' Sleeper Air Brakes & Power Steering 6x4 (SBA - Set Back Axle)</Description>
    </Vehicle>
    <Vehicle>
      <ID>131497</ID>
      <Product>TRUCK</Product>
      <Year>1993</Year>
      <Make>Freightliner</Make>
      <Model>FLD12064T</Model>
      <Description>120'' BBC Alum Air Cond Long Conv. (SBA) Tractor w/48'' Sleeper Air Brakes & Power Steering 6x4 (SBA - Set Back Axle)</Description>
    </Vehicle>
  </Vehicles>
  <Errors/>
  <InvalidVINMsg/>
</VINResult>
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
require 'csv'
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

    vincarriercsv = 'vincarrier.csv'
    vindetails = 'vindetails.csv'
    vinurl =  'http://redacted/LookUp_VIN?key=redacted&vin='

    CSV.open(vindetails, "wb") do |details|
        CSV.foreach(vincarriercsv) do |row|
            vinxml = Nokogiri::HTML(vinurl + row[1])
                make = vinxml.xpath('//VINResult//Vehicles//Vehicle//Make').text
                model = vinxml.xpath('//VINResult//Vehicles//Vehicle//Model').text
            details << [ row[0], row[1], make, model ]
        end
    end
```

For some reason the URL returns the same data twice but I only need the first result.  So far my attempts to grab the Make and Model from the XML has failed...any ideas?

Comment: I believe my issues are around this line: make = vinxml.xpath('//VINResult//Vehicles//Vehicle//Make').text

Comment: Yes, It is there. Do `vinxml.xpath('//VINResult//Vehicles//Vehicle//Make').map(&:text)`.. `vinxml.xpath('//VINResult//Vehicles//Vehicle//Make')` gives you `NodeSet`, you need to iterate through it to collect the *text* of each `Node`.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between `/` and `//` in XPath - double check your usage.

Comment: I don't think I want to iterate through the whole thing.  I just want the first Make and Model returned...What code would I need to include to get just that text?

Comment: `vinxml.xpath('//VINResult//Vehicles//Vehicle//Make').map(&:text).first`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to get at the make and model data. How to convert it to CSV is left to you:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<VINResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://basicvalues.pentondata.com/">
  <Vehicles>
    <Vehicle>
      <ID>131497</ID>
      <Product>TRUCK</Product>
      <Year>1993</Year>
      <Make>Freightliner</Make>
      <Model>FLD12064T</Model>
      <Description>120'' BBC Alum Air Cond Long Conv. (SBA) Tractor w/48'' Sleeper Air Brakes & Power Steering 6x4 (SBA - Set Back Axle)</Description>
    </Vehicle>
    <Vehicle>
      <ID>131497</ID>
      <Product>TRUCK</Product>
      <Year>1993</Year>
      <Make>Freightliner</Make>
      <Model>FLD12064T</Model>
      <Description>120'' BBC Alum Air Cond Long Conv. (SBA) Tractor w/48'' Sleeper Air Brakes & Power Steering 6x4 (SBA - Set Back Axle)</Description>
    </Vehicle>
  </Vehicles>
  <Errors/>
  <InvalidVINMsg/>
</VINResult>
EOT

vehicle_make_and_models = doc.search('Vehicle').map{ |vehicle|
    [
      'make', vehicle.at('Make').content,
      'model', vehicle.at('Model').content
    ]
  }
```

This results in:

```
vehicle_make_and_models # => [["make", "Freightliner", "model", "FLD12064T"], ["make", "Freightliner", "model", "FLD12064T"]]
```

If you don't want the field names:

```
vehicle_make_and_models = doc.search('Vehicle').map{ |vehicle|
  [
    vehicle.at('Make').content,
    vehicle.at('Model').content
  ]
}

vehicle_make_and_models # => [["Freightliner", "FLD12064T"], ["Freightliner", "FLD12064T"]]
```

*Note:* You have XML, not HTML. Don't assume that Nokogiri treats them the same, or that the difference is insignificant. Nokogiri parses XML strictly, since XML is a strict standard.

I use CSS selectors unless I absolutely have to use XPath. CSS results in a much clearer selector most of the time, which results in easier to read code.

`vinxml.xpath('//VINResult//Vehicles//Vehicle//Make').text` doesn't work, because `//` means "start at the top of the document". Each time it's encountered Nokogiri starts at the top, searches down, and finds all matching nodes. `xpath` returns all matching nodes as a NodeSet, not just a particular Node, and `text` will return the text of all Nodes in the NodeSet, resulting in a concatenated string of the text, which is probably not what you want.

I prefer to use `search` instead of `xpath` or `css`. It returns a NodeSet like the other two, but it also lets us use either CSS or XPath selectors. If your particular selector was ambiguous and could be interpreted as either CSS or XPath, then you *can* use the explicit form. Likewise, you can use `at` or `xpath_at` or `css_at` to find just the first matching node, which is equivalent to `search('foo').first`.

Comment: so would this return the first value for the first instance of Make in the XML? `vinxml.search('Make').first`

Comment: No, it would return the first matching Node, not its "value". You should use `at('Make')` if that's your intent. Add `text` if you want its "value". Remember, a Node is a location in the document. It's not the content of the node itself.

Comment: Thanks!  I was also opening the URL incorrectly but your patient responses got me to the finish line!

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the following which will place all of the vehicles in an `Array` and all of the vehicle attributes into a `Hash`

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(YOUR_XML_FILE))
vehicles = doc.search("Vehicle").map do |vehicle|
  Hash[
    vehicle.children.map do |child|
      [child.name, child.text] unless child.text.chomp.strip == ""
    end.compact
  ]
end
#=>[{"ID"=>"131497", "Product"=>"TRUCK", "Year"=>"1993", "Make"=>"Freightliner", "Model"=>"FLD12064T", "Description"=>"120'' BBC Alum Air Cond Long Conv. (SBA) Tractor w/48'' Sleeper Air Brakes  Power Steering 6x4 (SBA - Set Back Axle)"}, {"ID"=>"131497", "Product"=>"TRUCK", "Year"=>"1993", "Make"=>"Freightliner", "Model"=>"FLD12064T", "Description"=>"120'' BBC Alum Air Cond Long Conv. (SBA) Tractor w/48'' Sleeper Air Brakes  Power Steering 6x4 (SBA - Set Back Axle)"}]
```

Then you can access all the attributes for an individual vehicle i.e.

```
vehicles.first["ID"]
#=> "131497"
vehicles.first["Year"]
#=> "1993"
```

etc.